# Java Generics, Reflection API & JDBC: cannot map java.lang.Long and java.sql.Timestamp to a Type

Tags: java, generics, jdbc

Need a method to map the output of `ResultSet` to an instance of `LogEntity` using Generics and java.lang.reflect.*. Their is some constructor issue with Long & Timestamp field types.

JDK 1.8, Spring Boot 2.2.2, ***No I don't need your Hibernate or JDBCTemplate***

`LogEntity`:

```
package com.tb.register.core.entity;

import com.tb.register.core.annotation.ColumnName;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LogEntity {
  @ColumnName(name = "Rn")
  private Long rn;

  @ColumnName(name = "Id")
  private Long id;

  @ColumnName(name = "Name")
  private String name;

  @ColumnName(name = "Who_Made")
  private Long whoMade;

  @ColumnName(name = "When_Made")
  private Timestamp whenMade;

  @ColumnName(name = "Who_Made_Username")
  private String whoMadeUsername;
}
```

`ColumnName` annotation:

```
package com.tb.register.core.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ColumnName {
  String name();
}
```

Current method:

```
public List<V> getData(
      Connection connection, GridEntity gridEntity, Class<? extends V> classObject) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<V> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(gridEntity.getMainSQL());
      GridEntity.bindObjectLimit(preparedStatement, gridEntity);
      resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      resultSet.setFetchSize(300);
      Field[] fields = classObject.getDeclaredFields();
      for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        log.info("{}, {}", field.getName(), field.getType());
      }
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        V row = classObject.getConstructor().newInstance();
        for (Field field : fields) {
          ColumnName columnName = field.getAnnotation(ColumnName.class);
          if (columnName != null) {
            try {
              if (field.getType() == java.lang.Long.class) {
                field.set(
                    row,
                    field
                        .getType()
                        .getConstructor(java.lang.Long.class)
                        .newInstance(resultSet.getLong(columnName.name())));
              } else if (field.getType() == java.sql.Timestamp.class) {
                field.set(
                    row,
                    field
                        .getType()
                        .getConstructor(java.sql.Timestamp.class)
                        .newInstance(resultSet.getTimestamp(columnName.name())));
              } else {
                field.set(
                    row,
                    field
                        .getType()
                        .getConstructor(String.class)
                        .newInstance(resultSet.getString(columnName.name())));
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              log.error("", e);
            }
          }
        }
        rows.add(row);
        //        list.add(
        //            new V(
        //                resultSet.getLong("Rn"),
        //                resultSet.getLong("Id"),
        //                resultSet.getString("Name"),
        //                resultSet.getLong("Who_Made"),
        //                resultSet.getDate("When_Made"),
        //                resultSet.getString("Who_Made_Username")));
      }
      return rows;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("", e);
    } finally {
      PoolManager.release(resultSet);
      PoolManager.release(preparedStatement);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

What we get:

```
2020-01-18 21:33:47,754 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.entity.GridEntity: 
where: [], 
mainSQL: select * from( select /*+ first_rows(10) */ t.*, row_number() over(order By t.id asc) Rn from fr_cc_logs_v t ) where rn between :lowerLimit And :upperLimit order by rn asc
countSQL: select count(*) from fr_cc_logs_v t
2020-01-18 21:33:47,765 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: rn, class java.lang.Long
2020-01-18 21:33:47,767 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: id, class java.lang.Long
2020-01-18 21:33:47,767 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: name, class java.lang.String
2020-01-18 21:33:47,767 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: whoMade, class java.lang.Long
2020-01-18 21:33:47,767 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: whenMade, class java.sql.Timestamp
2020-01-18 21:33:47,769 INFO  [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: whoMadeUsername, class java.lang.String
2020-01-18 21:33:47,774 ERROR [http-nio-9111-exec-2] com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>(java.lang.Long)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository.getData(GenericRepository.java:63)
    at com.tb.register.core.repository.LogRepositoryImpl.getLogs(LogRepositoryImpl.java:74)
    at com.tb.register.core.repository.LogRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b1dfd861.invoke(<generated>)
```

...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.sql.Timestamp.<init>(java.sql.Timestamp)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.tb.register.core.repository.GenericRepository.getData(GenericRepository.java:70)
    at com.tb.register.core.repository.LogRepositoryImpl.getLogs(LogRepositoryImpl.java:74)
```

Comment: By the way: this problem is easy to see if you look at the stack trace: it's literally saying that there's a problem trying to get a constructor, and it tells you both the line number on which you're trying to get the constructor; and that it's a problem getting a constructor with something to do with `Long`. You could have cut down the amount of code shown in this question to approximately the snippet I showed at the top of my answer; it's fine then to ask "why does it fail/how do I fix it", but there is far less for people to hunt through to work out the issue.

Comment: i will take that into account with further questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (field.getType() == java.lang.Long.class) {
  // ...
  field.getType().getConstructor(java.lang.Long.class)
  // ...
}
```

This is trying to get a constructor in the `Long` class which takes a `Long` as a parameter.

There is no such constructor.

Perhaps you mean `getConstructor(long.class)`, which would select [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long-long-)?

Choose a constructor that exists. Or just skip the reflection:

```
field.set(
    row,
    resultSet.getLong(columnName.name()));
```

(You can do similarly for the other branches too. In fact, there's no need to invoke copy constructors for either, since you already can obtain instances of the correct type from the result set).

Comment: I like the skip reflection bit.. it worked thank you